# PHP's function to list all objects's properties and methods

Tags: php, oop

Is there a function to list all object's public methods and properties in PHP similar to Python's `dir()`?

Answer (score 18):

PHP5 includes a complete [Reflection API](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) for going beyond what the older [get_class_methods](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) and [get_object_vars](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) can do.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Reflection API's [`ReflectionClass::getProperties`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) and [`ReflectionClass::getMethods`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) methods to do this (although the API doesn't seem to be very well documented). Note that PHP reflection only reflects compile time information, not runtime objects. If you want runtime objects to also be included in your query results, best to use the [`get_object_vars`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), [`get_class_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) and [`get_class_methods`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) functions. The difference between `get_object_vars` and `get_class_vars` is that the former gets you all the variables on a given object (including those dynamically added at runtime), while the latter gives you only those which have been explicitly declared in the class.

Comment: I think there is an important point to be added when you say: "...get_class_vars gives you only those variables which have been explicitely declared in the class" and ALSO the associated VALUES are the ones declared in the class (the default values) and NOT the runtime values.

Answer (score 11):

```
Reflection::export(new ReflectionObject($Yourobject));
```

Comment: Note this returns a formatted string, not an array of attributes, like python's dir().

Comment: Export will be removed in PHP 8

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to list object variables and `get_class_methods` to list the methods of a given class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go deeper, and also get the private var of the object, you can use closure for that. like:

```
$sweetsThief = function ($obj) {
  return get_object_vars($obj);
};

$sweetsThief = \Closure::bind($sweetsThief, null, $myobj);

var_dump($sweetsThief($myobj));
```