# Show all public attributes (name and value) of an object

Tags: php, class, object, attributes

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372127/phps-function-to-list-all-objectss-attributes) didn't helped me.

If I use

```
$class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($this));

foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name : $value\n";
}
```

I get

attrib1_name : attrib2_name : attrib3_name

There are no values. Also a private attribute is shown, which I don't want.

If I use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_object_vars($this));
echo "</pre>";
```

I get

Array
(
    [atrrib1_name] => attrib1_value
    [attrib2_name] => attrib2_value
)

Here again I have a private attribute and all sub attributes. But this time I have the values. How can I constrain this to one level?

Isn't there a possibility to show all public attributes with their values of an object?

Comment: private properties are shown as you are calling get_class_vars from a scope where private props are visible. From the docs:`Depending on the scope, get_class_vars() will only return the properties that can be accessed from the current scope.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing non-public properties because `get_class_vars` works **according to current scope**. Since you are using `$this` your code is *inside* the class, so the non-public properties *are* accessible from the current scope. The same goes for `get_object_vars` which is probably a better choice here.

In any case, a good solution would be to move the code that retrieves the property values out of the class.

If you do not want to create a free function for that (why? seriously, reconsider!), you can use a trick that involves an anonymous function:

```
$getter = function($obj) { return get_object_vars($obj); };
$class_vars = $getter($this);
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pwUijI)**.

**Update:** Since you are in PHP < 5.3.0, you can use this equivalent code:

```
$getter = create_function('$obj', 'return get_object_vars($obj);');
$class_vars = $getter($this);
```

Comment: I thought I can use a `dump()` method which I can put in every class as a public function. Your approach with the anonymous function seems interesting. If I use your code I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in` te second line of your example.

Comment: @testing: That's because you are using PHP < 5.3.0. See my update.

Comment: You are right. I'm using PHP 5.2.9. Which part of your example isn't supported by PHP 5.2.9? Is there another way to rewrite your example?

Comment: @testing: The code above can be described as either cute or horrible, depending on who you ask. Consider sidestepping all that and creating a normal top-level function instead. Simple is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [php Reflection api](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Comment: Google " php reflection " and find some tutorials to learn from . I can assure you its a right path . After learning php reflection you can do alot more .

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Mr.Coder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009066/5808894), here is a snippet to fetch the public attributes of the object (name and value) as an array

```
public function getPublicProperties()
{
    $results = [];

    $reflectionObject = (new ReflectionObject($this));
    $properties = $reflectionObject->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $results[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($this);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use get_object_vars.
see: http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Answer (score -1):

I Fully recognize what you are trying to achieve so why not have something external like this to help out... (pasted from PHPFiddle)

```
<?php

final class utils {
    public static function getProperties(& $what) {
        return get_object_vars($what);
    }
}
class ball {
    var $name;
    private $x, $y;

    function __construct($name,$x,$y) {

    }

    function publicPropsToArray() {
        return utils::getProperties($this);
    }
    function allPropsToArray() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

$ball1 = new ball('henry',5,6);
//$ball2 = new ball('henry',3,4);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ball1->publicPropsToArray());
echo "\r\n\r\n";
print_r($ball1->allPropsToArray());

echo "\r\n\r\n";

?>
```

This way I can both access all properties of the object or for something such as a database access layer or similarly for a function that send "safe" data to a view or another un-privileged model I can send just the public properties, but have the behaviour defined within the object.

Sure this leads to coupling with a utility class, but to be fair not all couplings are bad, some are nesecarry to achieve an end goal, dont get bogged down by these things

Comment: I Just noticed that this has been downvoted. WTF, writing the same thing in every class is not a good idea, especially with anonymous functions, they should be used sparingly if at all, the good answers are to have a utilities class that is static or singleton, bootstrapped in the beginning of your program (my answer), or using a global function as Jon later says... to Jon, since it wont let me comment on your code, if you read this please respond I'd love to know your thinking behind anonymity for the sake of it and its effects on maintainability specifically